# Help! Baffling Syntax error 1084 in Actionscript expecting semicolon?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, syntax, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I've had these errors before, but I've been stuck on this one for hours :(

---

**Full error:**

```
Main.as, Line 513 1084: Syntax error: expecting semicolon before leftbrace.
```

---

**This is Line 513:**

```
} else (homeBool == false && embedBool == false) {
```

---

**Class where Flash CS5 gives me the compile error:**

```
// PlayerControls.as
private function drawControls():void
{
    // Home Page Player NOT autoplaying
    // Home Page Player Autoplaying
    // Non-Home Page Howdini Player

    if (homeBool == true && embedBool == true) {
        drawVideo();
        drawSplash();
    } else if (homeBool == true && embedBool == false) {
        drawVideo();

        // v Error highlights this line:
        } else (homeBool == false && embedBool == false) {
            drawVideo();
        }

    pc = new PlayerControls();
    pc.drawControls(playerW, playerH, embedBool);           
    pc.y = controlsY;
    pc.addEventListener("onPlay", vd.playVideo);
    pc.addEventListener("onPause", vd.pauseVideo);
    pc.addEventListener("embedSplash", hideSplash);
    stage.addChild(pc);
}
```

Any ideas or syntax errors I'm probably missing?

Please let me know if anyone needs to see more code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're missing an 'if' after the 'else' on that line. I'm not 100% sure without running some similar code, but usually if you use 'else' on its own, you don't include any parameters like you have done. So if you want those other checks, use 'else if'.

Hope it helps.

Comment: omg thanks! lol I've been working too late on this, I even looked up if else statements in my Essential ActionScript 3.0 book and just read the whole code block wrong. } else {

Comment: No probs :) Was a close race to this answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

that final else, should either be an else if, or remove the check

Answer (score 2):

You are missing an `if` statement after your `else` :

```
else if (homeBool == false && embedBool == false) {
            drawVideo();
        }
```